# How to add user as a co-owner of a file in Box.com

Tags: box-api

Can we add an user as a co-owner of record/file in a folder in Box.com ?

What I know we can add an user as a co-owner of a folder in Box.com by using this

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/collaborations \
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" \
-d '{"item": { "id": "FOLDER_ID", "type": "folder"}, "accessible_by": { "id":   GROUP_ID"}, "role": "editor"}' \
-X POST
```

and 1 more doubt here role : 'editor' means co-owner of the file, am I right ?

Any suggestion.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly assign the `co-owner` role. The [Collaborations](http://developers.box.com/docs/#collaborations) documentation indicates that you can assign the following collaboration roles on a folder:

```
editor
viewer
previewer
uploader
previewer-uploader
viewer-uploader
co-owner
```

Comment: Thank you @John Hoerr. Can we add an user as a co-owner to a file in Box.com?

Comment: Yes and no. The roles are applied strictly at the folder level. If you make a user co-owner of the folder, they'll be co-owner of every file and folder contained therein. But you can't make them (for example) a co-owner of one file and just a viewer of another file in the same folder.